# Mocking graph-ql requests

Tags: angular, graphql, mocking, apollo, graphql-js

I'm frontend developer in angular typescript and I'm trying to figure out how to mock graphql requests(I'm using Apollo-angular).

We decided to use graphql for new functionality in our app but it's the first time we'll be working with graphql. It'll be a while before I'll have requests ready so I wan't to mock something on frontend so I'll have something to work with. I'm having problems understanding how to mock requests since every example i find online seems to be quite different. Could someone propose the easiest/ simplest way to mock graphql requests in angular typescript using apollo client?

Thank's in advance.
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

[mswjs](https://mswjs.io/) supports [Mocking GraphQL API](https://mswjs.io/docs/getting-started/mocks/graphql-api).

Mock Service Worker operates client-side by registering a Service Worker responsible for requests interception.

So you can respond to a GraphQL operation(`Query`, `Mutation`) using a mocked response.